# How to wirelessly share tablet screen with someone far away?

Tags: hardware, tablet, screen-sharing

I bought an Android tablet for my grandma (Amazon Fire 8 HD -  but I got Google Play Store working) and if she has any questions I want her to be able to share her screen with me (I live far away).

I want to see her tablet screen on my Android phone or my PC.
As an additional feature I would like to be able to talk to her to say what she should do.

Basically what I want is exactly what Skype can do on a PC (talking and screen sharing) unfortunately the Skype Android app can't do that(?).

I found a few apps like "ScreenShare" and others but they didn't seem to work when our devices are in different WiFi Networks. Does anyone know an app or a way that can do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using computer**

I think the best mobile screen share is to show the screen on your computer and then share your computer screen with your friend.

1. user the **vysor** to share your Android device screen on your computer with Chrome easily and quickly.
2. then use **TeamViewer** to share screen with friends quickly

both of them are free for personal use and I had used them to help my parent to solve the issue on their mobile phones.

**Control Mobile Directly**

The another suggested app: [TeamViewer QuickSupport app](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/use-cases/mobile-device-support/)

1. install TeamViewer on your computer
2. install TeamViewer QS on your grandma's tablet, get the "Your ID"=> ID
3. Use the ID in step2 to send a request to connect your grandma's tablet.
4. Your grandma need to accept the request
5. Then you will see the screen on your computer

[image]

6. You can request screen capture, remote control, and see the app list on this interface.
7. Maybe the remote controlling needs root permission on the tablet. If it need, please try to install Super Su.

Comment: I read the vysor instructions, it says I have to connect the device to a computer...my grandma only has a tablet...no computer, so it won't work this way :(

Comment: OK, I think the best solution is using the TeamViewer Quick Support App (https://www.teamviewer.com/en/use-cases/mobile-device-support/). You need to install a host TeamViewer Software on your computer and use the "Your ID" of Quick Support App on your grandma's table to connect it. This app is designed for the IT support for mobile users.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I just got back home so now it's gonna take longer to try this out because I'm gonna have my grandma do all the steps on the tablet :D - I will accept ur answer if it worked in a few weeks I think!

Comment: That's ok Cheer

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was correct for 2016, in 2020 there are much easier solutions.

Firstly, Skype added this feature by now and otherwise there is also Facebook Messenger and probably others.

A solution I found however is even more simple and requires a one time installation of one app called [Screen Meet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projector.screenmeet) on your grandmothers device for example and accessing the stream through a link just like you twitch does.